# Authenticate with cas using bash, curl commandline

Tags: bash, authentication, curl, command-line, cas

I found this script for authenticating with cas to obtain a protected URL, from the commandline, using curl and bash(See code below). However, I could not get the script to work. I have verified that I am able to extract the LoginTicket, the JSESSION and provided the right username and password. However, it seems the cas-server does not react to it even though I have verified I provide it with all the right info. It just returns the login-page again and again without any error messages.

Is this script still a viable way of doing this? Or do I need to use the cas REST-API, if I want to get a valid cas ticket using the commandline, now adays?

```
# Taken from https://gist.github.com/dodok1/4134605
# Usage: cas-get.sh {url} {username} {password} # If you have any errors try removing the redirects to get more information
# The service to be called, and a url-encoded version (the url encoding isn't perfect, if you're encoding complex stuff you may wish to replace with a different method)
DEST="$1"
ENCODED_DEST=`echo "$DEST" | perl -p -e 's/([^A-Za-z0-9])/sprintf("%%%02X", ord($1))/seg' | sed 's/%2E/./g' | sed 's/%0A//g'`

#IP Addresses or hostnames are fine here
CAS_HOSTNAME=team.eea.sk

#Authentication details. This script only supports username/password login, but curl can handle certificate login if required
USERNAME=$2
PASSWORD=$3

#Temporary files used by curl to store cookies and http headers
COOKIE_JAR=.cookieJar
HEADER_DUMP_DEST=.headers
rm $COOKIE_JAR
rm $HEADER_DUMP_DEST

#The script itself is below

#Visit CAS and get a login form. This includes a unique ID for the form, which we will store in CAS_ID and attach to our form submission. jsessionid cookie will be set here
CAS_ID=`curl -s -k -c $COOKIE_JAR https://$CAS_HOSTNAME/cas/login?service=$ENCODED_DEST | grep name=.lt | sed 's/.*value..//' | sed 's/\".*//'`

#Submit the login form, using the cookies saved in the cookie jar and the form submission ID just extracted. We keep the headers from this request as the return value should be a 302 including a "ticket" param which we'll need in the next request
curl -s -k --data "username=$USERNAME&password=$PASSWORD&lt=$CAS_ID&_eventId=submit" -i -b $COOKIE_JAR -c $COOKIE_JAR https://$CAS_HOSTNAME/cas/login?service=$ENCODED_DEST -D $HEADER_DUMP_DEST -o /dev/null

#Linux may not need this line but my response from the previous call has retrieving windows-style linebreaks in OSX
#dos2unix $HEADER_DUMP_DEST > /dev/null

#Visit the URL with the ticket param to finally set the casprivacy and, more importantly, MOD_AUTH_CAS cookie. Now we've got a MOD_AUTH_CAS cookie, anything we do in this session will pass straight through CAS
CURL_DEST=`grep Location $HEADER_DUMP_DEST | sed 's/Location: //'`
curl -s -k -b $COOKIE_JAR -c $COOKIE_JAR $CURL_DEST

#If our destination is not a GET we'll need to do a GET to, say, the user dashboard here

#Visit the place we actually wanted to go to
curl -s -k -b $COOKIE_JAR "$DEST"
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try extracting the "execution" value like you do the "lt" value and including it in the second curl call.